# jQuery only being applied to a single button, not all instances of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with a dynamic number of buttons all with the id "delete-button". My jQuery works great, but only on the first instance of "#delete-button".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#delete_button').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').css('border-left', 'solid');
        $(this).closest('tr').css('border-left-width', '2px');
        $(this).closest('tr').css('border-left-color', '#dd3333');
    });
    $('#delete_button').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').css('border-style', 'none');
    });
});
```

What cold be causing this? Can I not have more than one button with the same id?

Comment: You are only targeting one single button, as ID's are unique and you can only have one button with that ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are multiple elements with the same id, the id selector will only get the first one. You should be using class names instead. e.g.

```
$('.delete_button').mouseleave(...
```

Answer (score 2):

**Id** should be unique (only one). Use .delete_button **class** instead.

```
    <button id="delete_button1" class="delete_button"></button>
    <button id="delete_button2" class="delete_button"></button>
    ....
    <button id="delete_buttonN" class="delete_button"></button>

    $(function(){
     $('body').on('mouseenter', '.delete_button', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').css({
                                  'border-left' : 'solid',
                                  'border-left-width' : '2px',
                                  'border-left-color' : '#dd3333'
                                 });
     });

     $('body').on('mouseleave', '.delete_button', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').css('border-style', 'none');
     });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

both answers are correct, but to elaborate on that just a touch. Valid html dictates that you cannot have the same id on multiple elements in a given page. Id's are meant to be a unique identifier for an element. Jquery treats this as though there can truly be only one id on the page so it will stop looking through the dom for more elements that match the id selector once it has found one. If you want to apply your logic to multiple elements with the same call, you must assign a class to those elements as they are meant to be used multiple times. jquery knows this and will find all elements that match your class selector.